# map structure member to key

Tags: c++, struct, mapping, backend

I want to fetch value of certain key from back-end.

In back-end the structures are defined and values are initialized. 
Consider this as structure defined in back-end:

```
struct person{
    string nme;
    string adrs;
    int id;
};

person p1 = {"steve","ABC street",23};
```

The key *address* corresponds to value of *p1.adrs* in back-end.

Now the key *address* is to be mapped to (p1 & adrs) in external file and should get the value "ABC street".

My question is how mapping is to be done for key and its particular structure member in external file and how to fetch value for that key.

Here Can I use std::map concept for this?

Comment: Where does this "key" come from? What is the purpose of your mapping? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve (please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))?

Comment: You might use some reflection library (as boost hana) and use macro (`BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT`) to define your struct to have the reflection .

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is the actual problem. As explained, I should get value of corresponding key from structures in back-end. This current funtion is to be called from other cpp program to map key and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for requirement. But to improve it further, mapping is to be declared in separate file (Here it was declared in .h file)

myfile.h

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Chassis
{
    string InLED;
    string AstTg;
};

struct Manager
{
    string MngrType;
    int count;
};

  const Chassis chassis1={"On","null"}; 
  const Manager manager1={"BMC",23};    

  const map<string, const string>cha1={{"IndicatorLED", chassis1.InLED},{"AssetTag",chassis1.AstTg},{"ManagerType",manager1.MngrType}};
  const map<string, int>cha2={{"Count",manager1.count}};

void func(string);

#endif
```

myfile.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myfile.h"
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void func(string item)
{ if(cha1.find(item) == cha1.end()) {if (cha2.find(item) == cha2.end()){} else {cout<< item<<":"<<cha2.at(item)<<endl;} }
  else {cout<< item<<":"<<cha1.at(item)<<endl;}
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "myfile.h"

int main() {
string item="IndicatorLED";
func (item);

string item1="AssetTag";
func(item1);

string item2="ManagerType";
func(item2);

string item3="Count";
func(item3);    
}
```